# Migrate Power Virtual Agents (PVA) web version to Microsoft Teams version

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-virtual-agents

I have created a full and rather complex Power Virtual Agents (PVA) bot using the web version (https://web.powerva.microsoft.com) on a free trial. I did not understand my organizational licensing very well then but now I understand that my organization does not have a PVA web license but we do have PVA for Teams included in our Microsoft Teams license.

**Is there a way that I can migrate my PVA for web bot to PVA for Teams?** Strictly speaking, what I need to transfer is the topic with branching logic. If I can migrate that but have to configure all other settings, that is fine for me.

I have searched extensively for this and all that I have found suggests that they are two different frameworks. Apparently, I can indeed [export and import PVA for web using PVA "solutions"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/authoring-export-import-bots?tabs=preview) and I can [export and import PVA for Teams using Dataverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/teams/import-solution-in-teams#import-customizations-into-dataverse-for-teams?WT.mc_id=BA-MVP-5003806), but it does not seem that these export and import solutions are compatible. I want to avoid having to create the entire bot from scratch.

Is there a solution that can work for me? If, for example, I could convert just the topics (with branching logic) exported from PVA for web into the same format as the PVA for Teams export, then that could work. But I have no idea how to do such a thing.

Comment: Since your question is mainly related to Power virtual agent, please consider posting in the [Power Virtual Agent Community](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Virtual-Agents-Community/ct-p/PVACommunity).